# Strutctural Equation Modelling (Path Analysis) How to Automatically Specify Model Syntax

Tags: r, r-lavaan

Anyone know if there is an easy way to write out the path models? Like in AMOS with the graphical interface and the model syntax is done behind the scenes. I'd like to do this for a model but I am using `lavaan` in R and have to write my model syntax but I don't want to make any mistakes - any easy way to draw the boxes and arrows and see what the syntax looks like afterwards?

Comment: There is *lavaanPlot* - see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lavaanPlot/vignettes/Intro_to_lavaanPlot.html

Comment: Not necessarily drawing the boxes and arrows and writing the syntax afterwards, but at least you could slowly develop the syntax and confirm as you go...

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that....making sure the syntax is correct is my concern but having a diagram to go along with that will help my confidence in knowing I am specifying it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `lavaan` I believe you have to specify the full model syntactically, although there are ways to plot the path diagram after you have manually specified the model: https://statistics.ohlsen-web.de/sem-path-diagram/

If you're looking for a free GUI for specifying SEM models you can try something like Onyx: http://onyx.brandmaier.de/

Comment: Onyx is something I had downloaded but not realized the syntax gets specified for `lavaan` specifically. Thanks!

Comment: so I dont think it will give you the R syntax directly - I dont think there are any programs that will write the R syntax for you. Onyx just functions as a graphical interface for specifying models without syntax, but I havent played with it much so maybe theres a way to get R/lavaan syntax from it...

Comment: You can show show script and pick lavaan as an option.